# Moving a file using PuTTY

Tags: linux, bash, putty, cp

I am newbie struggling to move a file on a Linux VPS using PuTTY.

I can log in with a user in PuTTY at this point I can navigate to see the file I wish to move (`~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war`).

By using `cd ..` a couple of times from the directory I begin at when I first log in to PuTTY I can then navigate to the location I wish to move the file to:
`usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps/`

I know that I need to use `cp` to copy the file and have tried variations on:
`cp ~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps`

However each time I get 'No such file or directory'

I have tried excluding the `~/` and the start and I have tried specifying `solr.war` at the end of the command.

Please excuse the newbie question, but I would really appreciate some advice on what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Download WinSCP and log in using the same credentials.  It's likely to work and will be a better interface if all you want to do is move files.

Comment: shouldn't it be /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps (slash at front before usr) ?

Comment: @ultrasawblade Does that support copying/moving on the remote machine? It's not very elegant to download to the local machine and then upload again.

Answer (score 1):

Some general notes:

- The format of the copy (`cp`) command is `cp source destination`
- In the *nix (Unix, Linux etc) world, directories are represented by `/` as opposed to `\` in Windows. The `root` of the filesystem (Windows' `C:\`) is `/`. So, the Windows path

  ```
  C:\Directory\Subdirectory\file.txt
  ```

  is this on Linux

  ```
  /Directory/Subdirectory/file.txt
  ```
- `~/` is your home directory, also known as `$HOME`.
- You don't need to `cd` to the directory you need to copy things to/from, you can just give the full path to it.
- You don't need to type the entire path out. On most Linux systems, when you start typing a path, you can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete it. If there is more than one possible completion, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to see them. For example, type

  ```
  ls /bo
  ```

  and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will automatically be completed to

  ```
  ls /boot
  ```

So, putting all this together, instead of writing the whole path, try writing the beginning and using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete. I suspect your file is not in `~/servers` but in `/servers` so try:

`cp /servers/apac` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Does that autocomplete? If not, try

`cp ~/servers/apac` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Once you find the correct source directory, use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> trick again to find the right destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are typing exactly:

`cp ~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps`

try typing this instead:

`cp ~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps`

Without the `/` in front of `usr` it's likely trying to go to your current directory plus `usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps` instead of off `/`.

EDIT: If you really have a `usr` directory in your home directory and are trying to copy to something like `/home/your_user_name/usr/local...` then specify the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a file requires two things:

1. Correct locations
2. Correct permissions

Looks like you are struggling with the location part.

Try navigation to both locations and running the command "pwd".  pwd returns the complete file path of where you are.

Copy the pwd output from both locations to use your cp command.

Example

```
cp 'pwd output source'/solr.war 'pwd output destination location'
```

For permissions:
You need to verify that you have permission to write to the destination you are trying to write to as well as read the file you are trying to read.  Do an ls -al on the file you are trying to copy and an ls -al on the destination folder, and provide that output.  You can also Google file permissions.  Or you can read this article to understand the permissions for yourself:
http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml

Comment: I thought this at first too but he left `/` off of `usr...`

Answer (score 0):

You skipped `/` before `usr`.

Solution (first line yours, second correct):

> cp ~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war
> usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps
>
> cp ~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war
> /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps/

I recommend you to review [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcCT7cbBY4o) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE_WzWR2IwY) short videos to understand basic Linux terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was based on a combination of contributions from the other answers - thank you all. september and ultrasawblade were correct to point our that i needed a forward slash before usr:

```
    cp ~/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps/
```

Thanks gabe for pointing out the possibility of permissions problems. So for me the above command didn't work because I didn't have the correct permissions as the user I was logged in as.

Thanks terdon for pointing out that `~/` means the home directory for the current user which is basically equivalent to `/home/username/`. Knowing this meant I could log in as the root user (avoiding permissions issues) and type the following command (which worked):

```
    cp /home/username/servers/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/webapps/solr.war /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps/
```

Thanks for all of your help with this. Gabe and septemebr - thank you for the links to those resources - they were helpful.